# Separator not aligned with Cell on Datagrid

Tags: wpf

I need to add a separator between some columns of my Datagrid, what I did so far is:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="SU" x:Name="Column7"/>

<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="1" CanUserResize="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="PG" x:Name="Column8" />
```

the result is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRqwZ.png)

any idea?

update

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Gray"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You forgot to post your CellStyle...but what's wrong with using the HorizontalGridLinesBrush and VerticalGridLinesBrush properties?

Comment: @mm8 sorry added now, I don't know the properties that you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `GridLinesVisibility` property of the `DataGrid` to indicate which grid lines will be shown and use the `HorizontalGridLinesBrush` and `VerticalGridLinesBrush` properties to change the colour of these grid lines:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray" GridLinesVisibility="All" ... />
```

This is way much easier than trying to use a `CellTemplate` to create grid lines.

**Edit:**

If you only want a vertical grid line for a specific column, you could adjust the margin of the `Rectangle` in the `CellTemplate`:

```
<Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Gray" 
           Margin="-1 0 0 0" Width="1"/>
```

Comment: but this will add the separator for all column, I need for specific column

Comment: Try to adjust the margin of the Rectangle. See my edit.

Comment: I need to create cell template for each column?

Comment: No, just modify your DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle.